# Shortcut to ps1 file on unc path not working

Tags: powershell, unc

Im trying to open a ps1 file that is in a UNC folder on the network using a shortcut.
it works on a local c: drive with no spaces in the name
The shortcut target is set to the below

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden \\share\info folder\somewhere else\thisfile.ps1
```

When i click it it doesn't open i have also tried without -windowstyle hidden and still no luck.

im sure i have missed something simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have spaces in the path, you should encapsulate it with quotes and I think you need the -file switch (don't know the other ones you are using) :

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -file "\\share\info folder\somewhere else\thisfile.ps1"
```

Comment: I had tried that but missed putting -file before the path Thank you :)